# How to create a numeric array of elements in associative array by type

Tags: php, arrays, string, int, double

How can i create a new array from elements in associative array in the way that if values is integer then put that value on first place in a new array,on the second place  put double,on the third place string, and on the last place number of elements. I try something like this but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$array = array ('first' => 2.54, 'second' => "foo", 'third' => 1);
function myFunction($array)
{   $NewArray = array ();
    $[3] = 0;
foreach($array as $value)
{
    if(is_integer($value))
    {echo $NewArray[0] = $value.' ';}
    if(is_double($value))
    {echo $NewArray[1] = $value.' ';}
    if(is_string($value))
    {echo $NewArray[2] = $value.' ';}
    echo $NewArray[3] += 1 . ' ';}
    return $NewArray;}
MyFunction ($array);
?>
```

Comment: What's the expected output? Describe how is this not working. Is this the actual code you tested, because `$[3] = 0;` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathieu Imbert is right and you didn't describe what was wrong when you ran the code.  I corrected it based on what `myFunction` should return (as specified in your question).

You shouldn't concatenate those values with string `' '` unless you want it with the space after the value. Finally if you want number of elements on 3rd position in returned array, don't concatenate the counter with `' '` - with that concatenation the counter would be `'1 1 1 '` (for sample array from your question). Without it - `3`.

Here's the corrected, tested code (I took the liberty of reformatting your code to make it easier to read and added `print_r()` for prettier output):

```
<?php
    $array = array('first' => 2.54, 'second' => "foo", 'third' => 1);
    function myFunction($array) {
        $newArray = array();
        $newArray[3] = 0;
        foreach($array as $value) {
            if (is_integer($value)) {
                $newArray[0] = $value;
            }
            if (is_double($value)) {
                $newArray[1] = $value;
            }
            if (is_string($value)) {
                $newArray[2] = $value;
            }
            $newArray[3] += 1;
        }
        return $newArray;
    }
    print_r(myFunction($array));
?>
```

which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 3
    [1] => 2.54 
    [2] => foo 
    [0] => 1 
)
```